# why does subshell returns if: command not found

Tags: shell, expression, subshell

Let's assume the following script:

```
echo "if test 1 -eq $1 ; then echo ls;fi" | tee /tmp/toto
cat /tmp/toto
$(cat /tmp/toto)
```

While running it with this command:
`./non_secure_script 1`

I get the following error:
`if: command not found`

However, the following command run with success:

```
$(if test 1 -eq 1; then echo ls;fi)
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: It's due to the order in which different components of the command line are processed. Just use `bash /tmp/toto`. Also `bash -c "$(cmd sub)"` and `eval "$(cmd sub)"` for command subs, but don't use that to execute a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because most parsing of traditional/standard (i.e. not *csh, rc, etc) shell input, in particular recognizing reserved words like `if` and compound commands like `if ...; then ...; fi` is done *before* expansions like `$( command )`. See the [sequence defined by POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04) particularly steps 2 and 3 and sections 2.2-2.4 later on the page, versus step 4 and sections 2.5-2.6 later on the page, *not* 'wordexp' as linked(!!!).

If you did `$(/tmp/toto)` or `$(. /tmp/toto)` -- or `$(source /tmp/toto)` on shells that have that as a synonym -- it would *execute* the if-construct in the subshell and return to the main shell only the string `ls` (or nothing). Since the main shell has parsed this as a simple-command (see section 2.9.1 on the page linked above) *before* expanding, and `ls` is a valid simple-command, it is executed successfully. Because word-splitting and pathname-expansion (often called globbing) are done (unless disabled) as the last steps of expansion in section 2.6, returning a string with multiple space-separated words like `ls -la` would work, unless they contain glob operators like `?` or `*`, but quoting like `ls -la 'file with spaces'` would not work.

Your second case `$(if...fi)` works for the same reason; it executes the if-construct in the subshell and returns only `ls` to be executed in the main shell, which is a valid simple-command.